# misbehaving of switch statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

here in this function firstly asking user to select one from rps array [rock paper and scissor] and secondly randomly choosing one from the array then it is assigned variable computer 
then finding index of both choosen option concating this indexes and assigned to variable comb and passing to switch statement to evaluate and show appropiate msg but in my code in switch statement only default statement is executing

please suggest me a solution..

```js
function RockPaperScissor() {
var rps = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
var player1 = prompt("Which one do you choose " + rps + "?");
var play1 = rps.indexOf(player1);
console.log("Player: " + play1);
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length);
console.log("computer: " + rand);
var computer = rps[rand];
var comb = play1.toString() + rand.toString();
console.log(comb);
if ((comb == '21') || (comb == '10') || (comb == '02')) {
    alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Congrats!!! You Won");
}
else if ((comb == '12') || (comb == '01') || (comb == '20')) {
    alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Sorry!!! You Lost");
}
else {
    alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Match got tied");
}
// switch (comb) {
//     case "21": alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Congrats!!! You Won");
//         break;
//     case "10": alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Congrats!!! You Won");
//         break;
//     case "02": alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Congrats!!! You Won");
//         break;

//     case "12": alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Sorry!!! You Lost");
//         break;
//     case "01": alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Sorry!!! You Lost");
//         break;
//     case "20": alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Sorry!!! You Lost");
//         break;

//     default: alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Match got tied");
// }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Random Switch</title>
    <script src="random_switch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <input type="button" value="Rock Paper Scissor" onclick="RockPaperScissor()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var comb = play1.toString() + rand.toString();` so `comb` is a string, not a number. also, `if ((comb = 21) || (comb = 10)` but `=` is assignment, not comparison

Comment: concating number with string the resulting output of type will be a string

Comment: @SagarS you are doing `play1.toString() + rand.toString()` which will give string representation of both the values so, `comb` is a string and use string value in `case`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here comb is of type string and in my cases i have passed a number so all the cases fails executing only default  satement

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use string value in switch `case` conditions since the `comb` is a `String` type and not an integer.

```js
function RockPaperScissor() {
    var rps = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
    var player1 = prompt("Which one do you choose " + rps + "?");
    var play1 = rps.indexOf(player1);
    console.log("Player: " + play1);
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length);
    console.log("computer: " + rand);
    var computer = rps[rand];
    var comb = play1.toString() + rand.toString();
    console.log(comb);
    switch (comb) {
        case '21': alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Congrats!!! You Won");
            break;
        case '10': alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Congrats!!! You Won");
            break;
        case '02': alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Congrats!!! You Won");
            break;
        case '12': alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Sorry!!! You Lost");
            break;
        case '01': alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Sorry!!! You Lost");
            break;
        case '20': alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Sorry!!! You Lost");
            break;

        default: alert("You choosed " + player1 + " and computer choosed " + computer + " Match got tied");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Random Switch</title>
  <script src="random_switch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="Rock Paper Scissor" onclick="RockPaperScissor()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bro i have switched to if statements here only if statement is executing please check that too

Comment: @SagarS you are assigning the value `comb = '21'` which is always `true` . You need to compare that as `comb ==  '21'`